# Python: psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL: connection limit

Tags: python, psycopg2

How do I resolve this error in my python script:

```
conn=psycopg2.connect(dbname=dbname, host=host, port=port, user=rsuser, password=password)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  connection limit "498" exceeded for non-superusers
```

I am connecting to a Redshift database, and my script was missing the connection close, 
but now how to I remove the connections so I can proceed?

Comment: Kill the processes keeping the connections open.

Comment: Yup, makes sense. Thanks. I could not figure out how I had caused the 498 number since I had only run my script a few times, but I found out that there is a bug in our app, not related to my script. There are other places in the app using the same connection.

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar issue, while making call to Redshift. Reduced batch size and it worked for me.
Try reducing the batch size for your call.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31139757)